# Unable to Run/Deploy Ionic application in Genymotion

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, adb

After running Genymotion virtual device, when I try to run ionic application, run command just hangs.

First of all "adb devices" returned no device listed. I used "adb connect" command to connect Geneymotion virtual device as shown below,

`C:\Users\Asif\myapp3>adb connect 192.168.56.101:5555
connected to 192.168.56.101:5555`

"ionic build android" command works fine and generates APK file but when I run "ionic run android" command it hangs and keeps on waiting as shown below,

```
C:\Users\Asif\myapp3>ionic run android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Asif\myapp3\hooks\a
fter_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\Asif\myapp3
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Asif\myapp3\platforms\android\cordova\run.
bat""
ANDROID_HOME=G:\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
```

Sometimes it process one step further and hangs at below stage,

```
C:\Users\Asif\myapp3>ionic run android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Asif\myapp3\hooks\a
fter_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\Asif\myapp3
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Asif\myapp3\platforms\android\cordova\run.
bat""
ANDROID_HOME=G:\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device '192.168.56.101:5555'.
```

Please advise. USB debugging is enabled in the virtual Device.

Here is my environment details,
Genymotion 2.6.0
Oracle VM Virtual Box manager 5.0.4
Virtual Device: Google Nexus 4 -5.1.0-API22-786X1280
Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version  0.6.5
OS: Windows 7 SP1  64 bit
Node Version: v4.2.1
java version "1.7.0_75" 64bit
AndroidManifest.xml entry: uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22"
SDK Tools for API22 already installed using "Android SDK manager"

Comment: did you enable USB debugging in ON in the virtual Device?

Comment: Yes, USB debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. The issue was due to Microsoft Security Essentials real time protection. I turned it off and it worked.